Cambiar el formato de fecha shortcode
Quiero obtener el formato correcto de fecha en un shortcode pero me sigue saliendo y/m/d. ¿Cómo haría para que me imprima d/m/y? ya intenté agregando en el mismo shortcode y no funciona. Gracias.
<?php
// Función para mostrar el perfil del usuario mediante un shortcode
function cumpleaños_usuario_shortcode($atts) {
    ob_start(); // Inicia el almacenamiento en búfer de salida
       // Verifica si el usuario está autenticado
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        // Obtiene los datos del usuario actual

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo esc_html($current_user->birthday_field) ;

    } else {
      
        echo '<p>Debes iniciar sesión para ver tu perfil.</p>';
    }

    return ob_get_clean(); // Devuelve el contenido almacenado en búfer de salida
}

// Registra el shortcode
add_shortcode('cumpleaños_usuario', 'cumpleaños_usuario_shortcode');

?>


¿Con qué formato viene la fecha en el shortcode? Te recomiendo que para trabajar con fechas uses la clase DateTime, la cual ofrece una flexibilidad enorme, haciendo fáciles tareas más o menos complicadas. Además facilita el control de nulos si hubiera fechas mal escritas. También, te recomendaría no usar ñ ni acentos en los nombres de funciones, variables, etc. En algunos casos el código se puede romper si la codificación no está bien configurada.

Entiendo que estas agregando algun tipo de hook/shortcode para Wordpress, parece que la fecha de nacimiento viene llamada por la function wp_get_current_user() que te devuelve el objeto user y al que accedes a la propiedad -> birthday_field.
Lo que puedes hacer es formatearlo con PHP directamente antes de imprimirla utilizando la funcion date:
...
$birthday = $current_user->birthday_field;
echo date('d/m/y', strtotime($birthday));
...

